# How does the Post back get reset ?

Tags: c#

Let me elaborate on this... I have the code below, there is a Page_Init (which I still don't understand why it fires more than once, but that is another story), and a Page_Load and I am checking for the "isPostBack" ... everything works great while I use my controls, radio button and drop down list, as well as Buttons; however, if I press the  key, even accidentally, the "isPostBack" is reset to False. What am I doing wrong? Also, my AutoEventWireup="true". 
Also, this is an .ascx file.

protected void Page_init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
        LoadPageText1();

        paymntpnl1.Visible = true;
        curbalpnl.Visible = false;
        paymntpnl2.Visible = false;
        paymntpnl3.Visible = false;
        paymntpnlcc.Visible = false;

}



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    LoadPageData();
    getContractInfo();
    step2lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    nopmt = Convert.ToDecimal(numpmts.Text);
    nopmt = nopmt * nopymts2;
    sb.Clear();
    sb.Append("$");
    sb.Append(nopmt.ToString("#.00"));
    nopymts.Text = sb.ToString();



    ValidateCC();
    chkNewCC();

    bool crdcrd = credCard;
    bool newcrd = nwCard;


    if (!IsPostBack){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking `IsPostBack` but you're still doing all the resetting before the check! And then the check makes no difference because it's an empty conditional block! You should be doing this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // All the initial setup that you don't want to do again goes here.
    }

    // All the stuff you want to do on first load AND PostBack goes here.
}
```

Make sure you [understand how conditionals work](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx&ei=svaEU5DHHoPmsASbn4DQDg&usg=AFQjCNEd_Xa3XoTkiBQTQom2sAS_9zU5GQ&bvm=bv.67720277,d.cWc).

Comment: yeah, maybe there is a sequencing issue here. this is driving me crazy, I forgot mention I am using asp:Panels, and I was thinking that maybe that technique is not the correct technique

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel There's nothing wrong with panels. You just have to understand the page load lifecycle.